# How to include object's parameters from YAML for Quarkus Rest API call?

Tags: java, openapi, quarkus

I'm a newbie in developing Quarkus api with OpenAPI YAML configuration. I have attributes declared in my YAML file for the various Objects. I'm getting my parameter from the call, where the user passes in a JSON and the return a JSON after executing couple of functions. I want to know if it's possible to use the example values from my YAML as input for my api calls. I was not able to find any documentation regarding, I've seen various documents about using YAML configuration for a database or some server, but this is specifically to get the input and use it as a parameter for the functions. If you guys can give me a hint or clue that would be wonderful.

I've seen various documents about using YAML configuration for a database or some server, but this is specifically to get the input and use it as a parameter for the functions. If you guys can give me a hint or clue that would be wonderful.

Comment: Hi, can you add some sample code describing approximately what you are trying to do? It will make things a lot of easier for readers of the question

Comment: the examples are applied as an example input on the Swagger page when you want to make an REST call (see: localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui)